# iOS How Array objects separated by commas convert into string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have an array named as `child_list` like child_list: "9,8,21,22,20,24,25", take it in `NSString` at index 0 when I convert it into string its work but when i use `NSMutableArray` it crashed, I don't know why.

My code is here:

```
if([theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"])
    {
        NSString *str = [[theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"]objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Child List %@",str);
        _child_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithObjects: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","], nil];
    }
```

When break point come on `str` it show result when it comes on `_child_list` it crashed.

Comment: does NSLog(@"Child List %@",str);  this log prints "9," . or just "9"

Comment: Create child_list as NSMutableArray. it will work perfectly. no need to change anything.

Comment: how about trying like that: _child_list = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","].mutableCopy

Answer (score 1):

Use **initWithArray** method while allocating _child_list NSMutableArray

```
 if([theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"])
    {
        NSString *str = [[theDictionary objectForKey:@"child_list"]objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Child List %@",str);
        _child_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithArray:[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
    }
```

Comment: What's the `, nil` for at the end? `arrayWithArray:` only takes one parameter. And my not simply use `mutableCopy` on the array?

Comment: @bhavesh taking arraywitharray like your code its occur an error

Answer (score 0):

Please share what your log returns and the dictionary you used..
The code `[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` returns an Array. So, when you're allocating a mutable array, you're creating array of array... Instead using `initWithObjects`, use `initWithArray` method and pass `[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` to it.

Comment: like that 
        _child_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithArray: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","], nil];

Comment: No, use it this way..  _child_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithArray: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];